# <a> link in a div hide/show with CSS not working

Tags: html, css, show, hidden

In this site I found and modified a CSS/HTML example. All seems go well but `<a>` link inside the div not working: its show without problems but when I click on them the only thing that happen is to hide the div and no more.

Here is the code:

```css
.clicker {
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-style: italic;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -2em;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
}
.hiddendiv {
  display: none;
}
.clicker:focus + .hiddendiv {
  display: block;
}
body#l-autore div.main div.hiddendiv ul.opere {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
}
body#l-autore div.main div.hiddendiv ul.opere li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<body id="l-autore" xml:lang="it-IT">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Brevi profili biografici degli autori</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <h1 id="sigil_toc_id_1">EXAMPLE</h1>
    <div class="clicker" tabindex="1">
      <h2 id="sigil_toc_id_2">
<p class="autori" id="id_romano">Romano</p>
</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="hiddendiv">
      <ul class="opere">
        <li>
          <a href="Cap02sez1.html">
            <span class="nr">I</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="Cap02sez2.html">
            <span class="nr">II</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Of course the two files `Cap02sez1.html` and `Cap02sez1.html` exist: before to put the link inside the DIV a normal  link open the right file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load the page, you're setting `display: none` on the div containing the links. Upon clicking on Romano, you're making them temporarily visible with `.clicker:focus + .hiddendiv`. However, that only applies when `.clicker` is in 'focus'. As soon as you click on one of the links, `.clicker` loses focus.

Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible to solve with raw CSS, as there is neither a `previous selector` nor `parent selector` in CSS. Therefor it is likely impossible to target the display of `.hiddendiv` from the child a link with raw CSS.

I would look into using JavaScript (preferably jQuery) to solve this with only a few small changes:

**HTML:**

`<p class="autori" onclick="show()"/>`

**CSS:**

`.visible {
    display: block;
}`

(Also remove the `.clicker:focus + .hiddendiv` selector)

**JavaScript / jQuery:**

`function show() {
    $(".hiddendiv").toggleClass("visible");
}`

Whenever you click on 'Romano', `.hiddendiv` will toggle between visible and invisible. I *believe* this is what you're after. If you just want to *show* it, and never hide it, you can use `$(".hiddendiv").addClass("visible");` instead.

Hopefully you're able to use JavaScript; otherwise I don't think this can be solved sorry!

### Updated Answer Without JavaScript

It's actually possible to solve your problem with raw CSS! You can simulate a button click in raw CSS, with some changes to the structure of your HTML. The **only** way to do this is by utilising a hacky version of `checkbox`. First, we put your `.clicker` inside the label for a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="show" />
<label for="show">
   <div class="clicker" tabindex="1">
      <h2 id="sigil_toc_id_2">
         <p class="autori" id="id_romano">Romano</p>
      </h2>
   </div>
</label>
```

Notice that the `clicker` div is now a label for the new input `#show`. Now we modify the CSS to reflect this, with a new target, while hiding the **real** checkbox:

```
#show {
    display: none;
}
```

We can then toggle the visibilty based on the `:checked` status of the invisible checkbox:

```
#show:checked ~ .hiddendiv {
    display: block;
}

#show:not(:checked) ~ .hiddendiv {
    display: none;
}
```

Naturally, you'll also need to remove both of the following:

```
.hiddendiv {
     display: none;
}

.clicker:focus + .hiddendiv {
     display: block;
}
```

Working sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/e4kd6zzy/) (with tidied code).

And thus, you have a visibility toggle for a separate div, with raw HTML and CSS :)

### Updated Answer With No JavaScript And Multiple Hidden Content Divs

It's quite possible to get this to work the same way with multiple different sections that are hidden. To do this, you simply create a range of hidden checkboxes that each *start* with the same name. Instead of using just `#show`, you would use `#show_1, #show2, #show_3, etc`. You can then target them with the CSS regular expression `[id^=show]`.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="show_1" />
    <label for="show_1"></label>
</input>

<input type="checkbox" id="show_2" />
    <label for="show_2"></label>
</input>
```

CSS:

```
[id^=show] {
  display: none;
}

[id^=show]:checked ~ .hiddendiv {
  display: block;
}

[id^=show]:not(:checked) ~ .hiddendiv {
  display: none;
}
```

Here's a [new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/gjw69xcv/) showing it working with multiple toggles controlling individual hidden divs :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Unfortunately i can only use css because (as h1 id can show) I'm working in a ebook 3.0 project. I know some JS can be used, but for more compatibility with the most of ebook reader on the market, i wanna use only css/html. So, can i leave the <a> links always visible and not turn them visible/invisible after first click on Romano link ?

Comment: It looks as though you've updated your code to add in some JavaScript, but if you want to only use CSS and HTML, it's easy enough to have the links visible all the time. Simply remove `.hiddendiv { display: none; }` :)

Comment: Can i leave  the <a> links always visible and not turn them visible/invisible after first click on Romano link ? (NOT always visible, but AFTER first click on Romano link! :-) ).

Comment: I just found a way to get the code to do exactly what you want without the use of any JavaScript. Please see my updated solution :)

Comment: Perfect! This last solution is OK for me. tnx a lot Obsidian Age. Have a good and rich new year 2017.

Comment: Sorry i talk too early. All is ok only for the first clicker but... it is a writers page, so i got 24 clicker, one for every author. And when i try to repeat your code every time i need it in the same xhtml page, only the first run. Please suggest me if continue here explaing or write a new question about it. thanx

Comment: @Latinoz71 Happy New Year to you too! Glad the solution worked for you. From what I understand, you have multiple sections like 'Romano' which each need to toggle different hidden content? That requires a slight change in the code structure, but is actually still possible! I've updated my solution to talk about this :)

Answer (score 0):

Because of the CSS style, the href link is disconnected before execution.

When you click the "I" or "II", code is loose every code in '.hiddendiv'.

So if you want to show and display the ".hiddendiv" with click event,

I suggest that **use the javascript with onclick event**

[What I do]

- Remove the css ".clicker:focus + .hiddendiv {display: block;}"
- Add the javascript to hide and show in click event.
- Change the 'a' to 'div' for using "onclick"
- When click the "I" or "II", execute the movePage function before hide the '.hiddendiv'

```js
function viewList(){
  document.getElementsByClassName('hiddendiv')[0].style.display = 'block'
}

function movePage(path) {
  window.location.href = path;
  document.getElementsByClassName('hiddendiv')[0].style.display = ''
}
```

```css
.clicker {
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-style: italic;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -2em;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
}
.hiddendiv {
  display: none;
}
.clicker:focus + .hiddendiv {
/*  display: block;*/
}
body#l-autore div.main div.hiddendiv ul.opere {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
}
body#l-autore div.main div.hiddendiv ul.opere li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<body id="l-autore" xml:lang="it-IT">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Brevi profili biografici degli autori</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <h1 id="sigil_toc_id_1">EXAMPLE</h1>
    <div class="clicker" tabindex="1">
      <h2 id="sigil_toc_id_2">
<p class="autori" id="id_romano" onclick=viewList()>Romano</p>
</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="hiddendiv">
      <ul class="opere">
        <li>
          <div onclick=movePage('Cap02sez1.html')>
            <span class="nr">I</span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div onclick=movePage('Cap02sez2.html')>
            <span class="nr">II</span>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Unfortunately i can only use css because (as h1 id can show) i'm working in a ebook 3.0 project.